# How to redirect info returned by Connect-ExchangeOnline to the variable

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am creating PowerShell script which runs some cmdlets and then return values in the form of JSON to external service.

What I am facing now is an issue with: Connect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet.

When there proper credentials are not passed, I get the following message in the console:

> Error Acquiring Token:
> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (NotFound).
> Error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (NotFound).*

I would assume that I could somehow catch this message or assign it to a variable, but somehow I am not able to do it.

I've tried:

```
try {
    $res = Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $a -ShowBanner:$false -ErrorVariable $z -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "Error: $errorMessage"
}
```

And also output redirection with `4>$null`, but still I receive the above-mentioned command.

I would appreciate your suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: You are performing an HTTP Request and getting back an HTTP Response.  The response is inside the $res.  It is not an exception.

Comment: PowerShell is not PostScript. Removing the tag.

Comment: Actually I am not using HTTP. I just want to prevent Connect-ExchangeOnline to return any value or to redirect the returned value to the output other than default. But no success so far...

Comment: @jdweng Actually when the password is not correct I receive the message into the console and it is not assigned to the variable. The question is:: how to assign it still to the variable or redirect output to the variable here?

Comment: First use Read-Host to get user input instead of redirect.  Then put password into Connect-ExchangeOnline command.